# Using % in an anonymous function

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I understand that given an anonymous function I can use the parameters like %1 %2, for example

```
(#(+ %1 %2 %3) 2 4 6)
```

But solving a problem

```
(true?  (x :a {:a nil :b 2}))
```

where x could be

```
#(nil? (%2 % %))
```

or

```
#(not (%2 % 1))
```

What does the % without been followed by a number means?

This is an exercise on [4clojure](https://www.4clojure.com/problem/134)

Thanks in advance

Comment: To be clear, `%` is not an operator, it is a component of a class of automatically generated bindings.

Comment: @noisesmith I removed the operator word from the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%` without any number is always equivalent to `%1` (i.e. the first argument to the anonymous function).

From the [docs](http://clojure.org/reader):

> `%` is a synonym for `%1`, `%n` designates the nth arg (1-based), and `%&` designates a rest arg.

I've seen mentioned (can't remember where but I agree) that it is always better to include the number in `%1` when the anonymous function takes more than one argument, since it is more clear to the reader.

Comment: https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide - "Prefer % over %1 in function literals with only one parameter.", "Prefer %1 over % in function literals with more than one parameter."